# Over-riding Standard Input and Output in C

Tags: c, unix, stdio, cat

I wrote this code for overriding the `cat` command in Ubuntu. The following three formats for `cat` instruction are working properly but rest are not working.

Working ones:

- ./catf > File.txt
- ./catf < File.txt

Not Working:

- ./catf File1.txt > File.txt
- ./catf File.txt

I am sending the terminal arguments to program as listed above. One other problem is every file also contains `Enter your String:` also which it shouldn't.Here is code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int readbytes,fp;
    char buf[1024];
    if(argc==1)
    {
        printf("Enter your String :\n\n");
        readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
    }
    else if(argc==2)
    {
        fp=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
        dup2(0,fp);
        close(fp);
        readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
    }
    else if(argc==3)
    {
        if(argv[1][0]=='<')
        {
            fp=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
            dup2(1,fp);
            close(fp);
            readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
        }
        else if(argv[1][0]=='>')
        {
            fp=open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);
            dup2(1,fp);
            close(fp);
            readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
        }
    }
    else if(argc==4)
    {
        printf("inside");
        fp=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
        dup2(0,fp);
        close(fp);
        fp=open(argv[3],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        dup2(1,fp);
        close(fp);
        readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);
        printf("%c",buf);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I made the changes suggested by William in the code and the rest of the code is working fine but this `./catf File.txt ">" File2.txt` is still not working. Why is that?

```
if(argc==4)
    {
        printf("inside4");
        fp=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);

        dup2(fp,0);

        close(fp);

        fp=open(argv[3],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRWXU);

        dup2(fp,1);

        close(fp);

        readbytes=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,1024);

        //printf("%c",buf);

        write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);
    }
```

What is the reason for above mentioned problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `cat > file1.txt`, `*argv[1]` is *not* `<`.  Rather, `argc` is 1 and stdout is already associated with the file by the time `main` is called.  If you want to pass `<` as an argument via the shell, you will need to quote it:

```
$ cat '<' filename
```

Also, your invocation of `dup2` has the arguments reversed;  `STDOUT_FILENO` should be the 2nd argument, not the first.  The way you have it in your `argc==2` clause is closing `fp` and reopening it to the original stdout.

Comment: Changing the name of the executable does not alter my answer in any significant way.  The only difference is that my example should be `./catf '<' filename`.  In terms of running the program, now `*argv[0]` is `catf` instead of `cat`, but `argc` is still 1, and `*argv[1]` is still NULL instead of `<` when you invoke the command as in your question.

Comment: Ok. why does the ones listed under `Not Working` are not working?

Comment: Because you are calling `dup2` with the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 0):

As @William Pursell says, redirection is handled by the shell, not by the program.  So the program never gets to see the redirection symbols in `argv[]`.

However you can tell if you have been redirected by testing `isatty(fd)`.  Unfortunately you cannot tell which file you are being redirected to in any standard way, for example you might be redirected to/from a pipe.

There is a possible hack on Linux, you could read `/proc/$$/fd` (where `$$` is your current PID) and look at the symbolic links for fds 0,1,2.  This is not supported on all UNIXs though.